# Visual Studio Code não reconhece o Rscript

Tags: json, r, visual-studio-code

Olá.
Instalei o VS Code 1.31.
Não estou entendendo por que o editor não está reconhecendo o RScript no "output", uma vez que no "terminal", está reconhecendo o R.
Segue o código no settings.json. 
O que não estou vendo?

```
{
  "r.rpath.lsp": "C:\\\\Program Files\\\\R\\\\R-3.5.2\\\\bin\\\\64\\\\R.exe",
  "r.interpreter": 1,
  "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\\\Program Files\\\\R\\\\R-3.5.2\\\\bin\\\\64\\\\R.exe",
}
```

Agradeço toda ajuda.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no seu `PATH` do terminal. Provavelmente vai ser que está parando em `bin` ou em `x64`. O `R` e o `Rscript` são programas diferentes, por isso o `Rscript` não deve estar funcionando no VScode, mas o `R` deve estar funcionando.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Vou olhar sim.